# Brackets in question titles

Tags: discussion, questions, formatting

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/194823/23547) includes brackets in its title:

> Do the relevant stats of a creature summoned via a "Summon [Creature Type]"-style spell change, if your stats change after you summoned it?

I can see the reason for the brackets - it is clearly indicating that OP wants to ask about a number of related spells such as *Summon Aberration*, *Summon Elemental*, *Summon Undead*, *etc.*

A more recent question, I believe [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/203953/23547), seemed related to me in the sense that it was asking about what happens to summoned creatures if the referenced statistics of their summoners change.  So I attempted to do the standard format "related" comment with a link to the prior question (I don't see my comment now so I expect it has been removed).

However, when posting the comment, I found that the brackets in the question title interfered with the link-recognition, such that the title was not linked to the question but rather all of the text was displayed, as in the first comment below.

This interference is not found with a question or answer box, such as the same text posted here will format correctly:

> Related: [Do the relevant stats of a creature summoned via a "Summon [Creature Type]"-style spell change, if your stats change after you summoned it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/194823/23547)

In such a case, should I simply remove the brackets (as in the second comment below), even though this results in not correctly reproducing the title of the question?

Should question writers be discouraged from using brackets in their titles?

Comment: Related: [Do the relevant stats of a creature summoned via a "Summon [Creature Type]"-style spell change, if your stats change after you summoned it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/194823/23547)

Comment: Related: [Do the relevant stats of a creature summoned via a "Summon Creature Type"-style spell change, if your stats change after you summoned it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/194823/23547)

Comment: @Exempt-Medic Obviously your comment format was successful - can you explain more what "escape characters" means?

Answer (score 4):

#### Special characters can be escaped with \

If you have text you want a link on such as

> Testing [link] ideas

You can escape any troublesome characters by placing a \ before them, which makes the parser treat them as regular characters and never special ones, such as the ones that indicate the parts of a link.

For example:

```
[Testing \[link\] ideas](https://rpg.stackexchange.com)
```

Yields:

> [Testing [link] ideas](https://rpg.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Regarding that last bit: looks like `\\[this\\]` is a novel way to invoke a MathJax block for some reason. It's supposed to be just `$$this$$` for blocks and `\$this\$` for inline.

Comment: @doppelgreener Yeah, that's what I figured it was. I wonder if there's some obscure way around it

Comment: I've updated this to use a code block to render the mathjax issue moot, and so also dropped the mathjax section. I asked separately about the mathjax issue [over here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12335/whats-going-on-with-this-sequence-invoking-mathjax).