# What's going on with \\[this sequence\\] invoking MathJax?

Tags: support, mathjax

Exempt-Medic noticed [in this answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12334/1204) that the following sequence invokes MathJax: `\\[MathJax!\\]`

See it here in action: \[MathJax!\]

Our configuration [ever since our original request to enable it](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6335/1204) was supposed to be `\$this\$` for inline MathJax (\$this\$) and `$$this$$` for blocks, but above `\\[this\\]` also invokes a block.

What's going on that `\\[...\\]` is invoking MathJax as well? Is it supposed to be doing that? Is this a bug or an expected feature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this meta.se answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375925/674198), `\\[ ... \\]` is one of the syntaxes used for “display style” math mode, the same environment as `$$ ...  $$`.